# Custom AsyncTaskLoader class doesn't honor calls to forceLoad

Tags: android, android-asynctask, android-loader, asynctaskloader

This is a bit of a weird problem. I'm using a class that extends AsyncTaskLoader (real deal targeting API level 11, not the compatibility one) to receive intents sent by another app component and respond by downloading some data from a local database. I initialize the loader using a LoaderManager in my main activity's onStart method.

When first started, the loader works fine. The following is a sequence of events that happens:
Activity.onCreateLoader - Loader constructor - Loader.onStartLoading - Loader.loadInBackground - Activity.onLoadFinished - Loader.deliverResult

However, when I exit the activity and re-launch it repeatedly, eventually it will stop working as expected. This would be the sequence:
Activity.onCreateLoader - Loader constructor - Loader.onStartLoading - nothing

There is a call to forceLoad inside Loader.onStartLoading, but in the latter case, it doesn't seem to do anything. All the places I've searched seem to say that calling forceLoad is a near-bulletproof way to get the loader to start doing its thing, but I keep running into cases where it simply does nothing. The properties of the loader are identical in each case (isStarted, isAbandoned, and isReset give the same result regardless). Frankly, I haven't found anything that is different about the loader between the cases when it works fine and cases when it doesn't load anything.

Comment: Can we get some sample code? What does Loader.onStartLoading() look like?

Comment: Did you ever resolve this issue? I'm experiencing the same problem.

Comment: I haven't, unfortunately. This was a long time ago, but I believe at the time I abandoned using AsyncTasks and did everything with simple threads.